# What to do with Extras.pkg when installing multiple versions of Mathematica?

Tags: installation

When installing Mathematica, there is a `Extras.pkg` part that one can install.  What does it contain?  When installing multiple versions of Mathematica, do I need to be careful with what version of Mathematica's `Extras.pkg` should be installed so potential overwriting does not cause undesirable effects?

Comment: This [How do I install Mathematica on Mac OS X?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12449) might be helpful. **Quote:** Mathematica may have an Extras package that allows you to view CDF documents when embedded in web pages and preview notebooks in your web browser. For more detailed information you should contact [Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).

Comment: Do I need to click and install Extras.pkg for every version of Mathematica I'm installing?  Will doing that overwrite each other and cause any undesirable effect?

Comment: Every Installer is accompanied by a unique Extras.pkg, since it contains Browser Plugin and Spotlight Plugin You are well advised to keep querying the support in this Case.

Comment: They won't respond in time (for my current need) --  That's why I ask here.  I'll take that as that I need to install `Extras.pkg` from the latest version of the different versions of Mathematica I'm installing.

Comment: I have v9 and v10 running on OSX 10.10.2 and running Extras.pkg from v10 installer, no harm so far on **my** System. Did so on iMac and MacBook.

Comment: That's all that I need for proceeding with my installation.  Thanks.