# What is included in Wolfram Extras?

Tags: system, installation

I recently installed a new version of *Mathematica* and it includes an optional companion package entitled "Wolfram Extras".
Is there any official documentation (release notes?) that details what programs, packages, or functionality are installed by this optional component?

After installation of 10.2, the *Mathematica* preferences dialog displays the following listing (next to the button "Install Wolfram Extras"):

> Wolfram System Browser Plug-in
>   *Not Installed*
>
> Notebook Indexer for Windows
>   *Not Installed*
>
> Notebook Indexer for Google Desktop Search
>   *Not Applicable*
>
> Notebook Indexer for Copernic Desktop Search
>   *Not Applicable*

The comments from user @Lou on this related question ([78536](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78536/what-to-do-with-extras-pkg-when-installing-multiple-versions-of-mathematica)) mention some of the things past "extras" packages have included:

- [functionality] that allows you to view [CDF documents](https://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) when embedded
  in web pages and [preview notebooks](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5596/) in your web browser.
- Browser Plugin and [Spotlight Plugin](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5614/).

---

**UPDATE**: In *Mathematica* 11.1 the "Install Wolfram Extras" button as well as the information about installed Wolfram Extras is [removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1pCY.png) from the "System" tab of the "Preferences" dialog. In version 11.0.1 this information is [available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqnnh.png).

Comment: On OSX at least, the Extras package currently only installs the browser plug-in. As far as I know, it installs nothing else (the Spotlight plugin has been removed).

Comment: @StefanR Why was the Spotlight plugin removed?  I find it quite useful to be able to check notebooks with QuickLook.  Are you saying that if I only ever had 10.2 installed, this functionality would not be available?

Comment: @Szabolcs The Spotlight Plugin is now contained inside the Mathematica app bundle itself, and does not need to be installed separately like it used to be. The plugin itself is alive and well :)

Comment: In *Mathematica* 11.1 the "Install Wolfram Extras" button as well as the information about installed Wolfram Extras is [removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1pCY.png) from the "System" tab of the "Preferences" dialog. In version 11.0.1 this information is [available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqnnh.png).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wolfram Extras on Windows as of version 10.2 include the following

- the browser addons, namely **npmathplugin.dll** (an [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) plugin, compatible with e.g. Firefox, but [no longer supported](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html) by Chrome) and **MathPlugin.dll** (ActiveX control for Internet Explorer), which are 
  typically installed under *C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Wolfram Research\Browser* along with the requisite MathLink libraries.
- the following search plugins, which are typically installed under *C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Wolfram Research\Search*: **CopernicNotebookIndexer.dll** for [Copernic Desktop Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copernic_Desktop_Search), **GoogleNotebookIndexer.dll** for [Google Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Desktop) 
  and **WindowsNotebookIndexer.dll** for [Windows Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search).
- the [EndNote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EndNote) citation management integration plugin, **MathEndNote.dll** typically installed under *C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ResearchSoft\EndNote\Plugins*.

On Mac OS X, as already mentioned in the comments, the **Extras.pkg** installer currently contains only the NPAPI browser plugin installed under */Library/Internet Plug-Ins*. The [Spotlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_(software)) search indexing plugin, **Wolfram Notebook.mdimporter** and [Quick Look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look) preview plugin, **Wolfram Notebook.qlgenerator** are no longer installed separately but are placed inside the **Mathematica.app** bundle.

On Linux, there are no Wolfram Extras.

Comment: Could you take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91934/12)?  I tagged it as bug but I'm less confident about it now.

Comment: Is there a way to check that the "Notebook Indexer for Windows" plug-in does work? For what is it intended for actually?

Comment: To index the contents of notebooks for Windows Search. Both .nb and .nbp should appear as registered file types in the indexing preferences, and performing a search should find any notebook files with matching contents.