# Reading a HDF file im Mathematica

Tags: bugs, import

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting though 10.2**

On OS X, the problem is present in 9.0 but not in 10.0, 10.1 or 10.2.

---

I am trying to read a HDF file in Mathematica 9 on OS X and get this message:

> LinkObject::linkd: "Unable to communicate with closed link
>   LinkObject[!(\"/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Converters/Binaries/MacOSX-x86-64/HDF.exe\",
>   247, 4)]."

Any clue what is going on ???

The command was:

```
Import["CAL_LID_L2_05kmALay-Prov-V3-02.2013-01-02T16-42-52ZD_Subset.hdf",{"Datasets", "Number_Layers_Found"}]
```

The file can be downloaded from http://ge.tt/3eSkGUM2/v/0?c

Comment: `HDF.exe` has likely crashed. To let people try to find a solution, you need to give more details: a small sample HDF plus the specific import command would be good.

Comment: Import["CAL_LID_L2_05kmALay-Prov-V3-02.2013-01-02T16-42-52ZD_Subset.hdf",{"Data", "Number_Layers_Found"}]

Comment: How can I add here the dataset I am using ?

Comment: Upload it somewhere and post a link.  I sometimes use http://ge.tt/, but you can use any service.

Comment: Here are the data: http://ge.tt/3eSkGUM2/v/0?c

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you were doing anything incorrectly.  I believe this is a bug in Mathematica 9.  In Mathematica 10 and later it works correctly.  You can try to extract that part of the data with some other tool, e.g. convert to text format and read with Mathematica afterwards.

Comment: On Linux, I get this error, for provided file, in all *Mathematica* versions I have available: 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.1 and 10.2.

Comment: In fact I am doing in MACOSX, which is unix after all.

Comment: @jkuczm You are right, it doesn't work on Linux.  On OS X it works fine with v10, 10.1 and 10.2.  Can you report it to support?

Comment: user10737, @Szabolcs I don't know much about HDF format, but *Mathematica* imports data, from provided file, correctly, in all versions I have available, not only after conversion to HDF5, but also after re-converting it back to HDF4 using h5toh4. Bug report should include example file that causes this error, I can't reproduce it with files that I create and I'm kind of reluctant to send report with someone else's data.

Comment: @jkuczm So perhaps the file is corrupted in some subtle way?  The only other software I tried was HDFView, which didn't complain.

Comment: @Szabolcs Perhaps, but since MMA 10 can read it on OS X, it should also on Linux.

Comment: @jkuczm I was thinking that if the file is corrupted and Mathematica doesn't do enough checks to notice that, it might cause an out-of-bounds array access or similar.  Whether that will lead to a segmentation fault depends on luck somewhat, so it can differ between OS and compilers.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that `HDF.exe` crashes.  This should not happen and I think this is a bug.  On OS X I can reproduce the crash with M9.0, but not with M10.0 or later.  On Linux I can reproduce the crash with M10.2 too.

A possible workaround is to convert the file from HDF4 to HDF5 format.  You could use [the `h4toh5` tool](https://www.hdfgroup.org/h4toh5/) for this, which I installed using MacPorts.  Mathematica 9 will read the resulting HDF5 file without problems.

Comment: I will try that !!! Thanks

Comment: Filed a bug report. Thanks for the heads up!